# How to set the stage to unstable in scripted pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

In scripted pipeline i am trying to check the status of the downstream job . if the downstream job is failed i want to set the stage as unstable . i am trying the below code but it does not work

```html
if (JOBRUN == "true" ){
    def downstream = build job: "/project/A/${env.BRANCH}", wait: true
    if (downstream.getResult() != 'SUCCESS') {
        unstable(message: "Downstream job result is ${downstream.result}")
    }
}
```

I have tried this option too

```html
def downstream = build (job: "/project/A/${env.BRANCH}", wait: true).result
if (downstream.getResult() != 'SUCCESS') {
            unstable(message: "Downstream job result is ${downstream.result}")
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jenkins automatically propagates the build result upwards so you don't have to specifically go and get the result from a method as the result is reflected in the status of the upstream build job. Instead, you can catch the error and change the result from your code. For example:

```
script {
    try {
        build job: 'yourjob', wait: true
    } catch (err) {                                        
        unstable(message: "abc")
    }
}
```

So in the above case, if `yourjob` fails, the entire stage that is triggering that job will also fail. However, since the failure is being caught, the error will be converted to `unstable` with whatever message you specify.